# Webforms buttons disabling randomly and intermittantly

Tags: asp.net, button, webforms

All over my application, buttons, link buttons and image buttons seem to become disabled.  A few refreshes of the page, or a reload, or sometimes it requires a restart of my browser (This occurs in all browser) will re-enable the button.  I haven't got a clue how this is happening and it is driving me, and my clients nuts.  I am assuming it must be something to do with the page lifecycle but can't understand why the issue is intermittent.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Is there any code in your application that disables controls for any reason? If so, how does it identify the control to be disabled? I've not seen any instance of controls becoming randomly disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the intial states of your buttons in the .aspx page.  See if it's all consistent as far as their Visible and Enabled properties.

Then identify any code in your code-behinds or javascript that would modify those properties.  (I always have a Sub called 'SetFormAttributes' in my maintenance pages)

Look for things that might inconsistently cause postbacks that you might not be seeing.

The key to finding this is to understanding everything that is or COULD be going on in that page.